# Tracking thru PDF

Tags: pdf

Is it possible to track PDF (who (IP) and when) whenever the user Opens the PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial version of the question seemed to suggest you want to know if 
author information can be carried in a PDF created by them that would 
indicate when and who created the PDF to others.

Your edited question seems to suggest you want to track where the PDF is opened.
This can probably be done with embedded things in the PDF.
There is some discussion on this at the Google forum thread [Advanced PDF Tracking](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=4f5ac49d153e42ec&hl=en)

It also links to this [Google Analytics without javascript](http://www.vdgraaf.info/google-analytics-without-javascript.html) blog post.

---

The idea required here is to trigger an active operation when the PDF is opened.